# Using Google direction API to draw route in map control?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps, windows-10-mobile

I want to draw a route in windows phone 8.1 map control,but i dont want to use the routefinder service of the map control,instead i want to use google direction api.
I was thinking of making the route instance myself and filling the values myself but as the fields are readonly and classes are sealed i cant do that .

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The terms of use of both Bing Maps and Google Maps do not allow mixing data between the platforms.